# VBA color fill macro from one sheet in rows to another sheet in columns

Tags: vba, excel

Still very new to Excel VBA. I need to conditionally copy color fills from cells on another worksheet that read from left to right and copies those colors on to another worksheet going in a column.  The biggest problem I'm having is organizing my nested for loops.  The idea is to populate a 7x7 array with input that'll be represented with the color.  The 7x7 array itself is going to be filled in entirely by columns but its reading off of rows in another worksheet.  The code below doesn't work.

```
Sub colorfillcopy()


  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer, 
  lastrow As Long


Dim Sourcews As Worksheet, Transferws As Worksheet
Dim row1 As Range, row2 As Range, row3 As Range, row4 As Range, row5 As 
Range, row6 As Range, row7 As Range
Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim rngPaste As Range




Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
Set Transferws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transfer")

Transferws.Range("row1:row7").Interior.Color = xlNone

lastrow = Sourcews.Cells(Sourcews.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastrowgrid = Transferws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To lastrow



         If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = " Conditionally data" And Transferws.Cells(18, 
                        Sourcews.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then

        For j = 1 To 7

                   For k = 1 To 7

                 Sourcews.Range("8 ,j+1").Interior.Color = 
                            Transferws.Range("P:V").Interior.Color



                Next k

         Next j

    End If



Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: *the code below doesn't work* - that is pretty vague. Please read how to [create a complete, minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: There are two parts that here, on SO, would cause it to break. Not sure if it's just because of your copy/pasting or not.  `If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i)...` line needs to all be on one. You break it after `.Cells(18,`.  Also the `Sourcews.Range("8,j+1")...` line A) that reference doesn't make sense, and you also need the `Transferws.Range(...)` on that same line after `=`, **or** connect the two by adding a `_` after the `=` .  First, can you please edit/update the code here to match how you have it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

again, Chicken_Milk; I've helped you a bit on here, recently!

First issues I see is a loop for "k", but no k is seen.  The loops you have should be sufficient, as you are using a loop for i, and if true you are looping for j.  I have corrected a couple errors such as putting items on separate lines (if you want to make stuff carry-over to another line, you need to use underscore).  The Range in the j loop has been changed to Cells, and the "" removed (if this is to be range, it will be similar to Range("A" & j+1), rather than commas.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer, lastrow As Long
Dim Sourcews As Worksheet, Transferws As Worksheet
Dim row1 As Range, row2 As Range, row3 As Range, row4 As Range, row5 As Range, row6 As Range, row7 As Range, rngCopy As Range,  rngPaste As Range

Set Sourcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")
Set Transferws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Transfer")

Transferws.Range("row1:row7").Interior.Color = xlNone

lastrow = Sourcews.Cells(Sourcews.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
lastrowgrid = Transferws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = " Conditionally data" And Transferws.Cells(18,Sourcews.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
        For j = 1 To 7
            Sourcews.Cells(8 ,j+1).Interior.Color =Transferws.Range("P:V").Interior.Color
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
```

I will say, i'm a bit confused by your If statement, what the requirement is for the second criteria ("if rng=B and x then" rather than "if rng=B and x=A then").

Comment: Thank you Cyril, the If statement is suppose to check two sets of conditions

Comment: @chicken_milk Would you please specify the second condition?  That's what I was getting at in the question after the listed code.  Condition 1 is AA&i.value="Conditionally data", Condition 2 is... ?

Comment: its supposed for the value that is referenced in Sourcews.Range("A" & i)

Comment: As written, condition 1 is **Sourcews.Range("AA" & i).Value = " Conditionally data"**; condition 2 is **Transferws.Cells(18,Sourcews.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column**.  The problem is that condition 2 has no criteria (needs to have = 'something' or isempty(), etc.).  Once we know what those conditions are and are supposed to be, then this should be wrapped up.  I believe, per your comment, that Condition 1 is supposed to be "A" not "AA", but that doesn't account for the second condition.